# Client Activated .NET Remote Object Version Difference Requires GAC

Tags: c#, remoting

I have am working with a .NET remoting service written internally, which has the following configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="tcp" port="7361">
                <serverProviders>
                    <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
                 </serverProviders>
             </channel>
         </channels>
         <lifetime leaseTime="5M" sponsorshipTimeout="2M" renewOnCallTime="2M" leaseManagerPollTime="10S" />
         <service>
            <activated type="MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly.MyClass" />
         </service>
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

I am using the following code to create an instance of an object on a remote server:

```
UrlAttribute att = new UrlAttribute("tcp://remoteserver:7361/");
MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyClass o = (MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyClass)
   Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyClass), new object[] {}, new object[] {att});
```

Someone who knew more about this than I created two implementations of `MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyClass`. One of them is in `MyCompany.MyAssemblyProxy.dll` and the other is in `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll`.

The proxy has a class hierarchy that looks like this:

```
[Serializable, SoapType(XmlNamespace=@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyCompany.Transaction/MyCompany.MyAssembly%2C%20Version%3D1.0.7300.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D541b4aff0f04b60a", XmlTypeNamespace=@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyCompany.Transaction/MyCompany.MyAssembly%2C%20Version%3D1.0.7300.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D541b4aff0f04b60a")]
public class MyClassBase : System.MarshalByRefObject
{
   // ... etc ...
}

[Serializable, SoapType(XmlNamespace=@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyCompany.Transaction/MyCompany.MyAssembly%2C%20Version%3D1.0.7300.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D541b4aff0f04b60a", XmlTypeNamespace=@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyCompany.Transaction/MyCompany.MyAssembly%2C%20Version%3D1.0.7300.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D541b4aff0f04b60a")]
public class MyClass : MyClassBase, MyCompany.Services.IMyAuthenticate
{
    // ... etc ...
}
```

The classes in the proxy look very much like an empty interface copy of the implementation that is in `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll`. The client application references `MyCompany.MyAssemblyProxy.dll` while the server (through all the invisible magic of .NET remoting) somehow ends up creating an instance of `MyClass` from `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll`.

Note that the version in the proxy attributes are hard-coded to 1.0.7300.0, but the AssemblyVersion on the files we're building is around 8.0.0.999. This all works fine under any of the following circumstances:

1. The client is referencing `MyCompany.MyAssemblyProxy.dll`, `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll` is installed in the server's GAC, and the version on the server is the same or different than the version on the client, OR
2. The the client references the same version of `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll` that is available on the server instead of referencing `MyCompany.MyAssemblyProxy.dll`. None of our code is in the GAC.

It fails when:

3. The client references `MyCompany.MyAssemblyProxy.dll` and the server does not have `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll` installed in the GAC (the error message is like `Cannot load type 'soap:MyClass, http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MyCompany.Transaction/MyCompany.MyAssembly%2C%20Version%3D1.0.7300.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D541b4aff0f04b60a'.`), OR
4. The client references `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll` and the server has an older version of `MyCompany.MyAssembly.dll` in the GAC.

I'm trying to retain the flexibility of having varying versions while eliminating the need to install assemblies into the GAC, but I can't figure out how.